# NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID google and windows certificate store

Tags: c#, google-chrome, .net-core, ssl-certificate

I am on a .NET 4.8 app using C# and this app generates a web page on the localhost user, and I am also using `X509Store`, `X509Certificate2`.

I am having a really unknown situation and behavior with generated stored certs on google, here how to reproduce it :

1. **I open google chrome first (IMPORTANT)**
2. I open multiple tabs : `https://localhost/` x 2, `https://127.0.0.1/` x 2, `https://192.168.0.12/` x 2 *(all of them will throw `NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID` which is normal since no cert has been stored yet)*.
3. I generate a basic cert allowing those SANs (Ip adresses of the host):
   `localhost`,
   `127.0.0.1`,
   `192.168.0.12`
   ...
4. I store it in the `StoreLocation.CurrentUser` with the `X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet` *(it can be `StoreLocation.LocalMachine` using `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet`, it doesn't affect the outcome)*.
5. I then go back on google and I refresh one of those tabs (it can be any one):

- -> **the first tab refreshed will ALLWAYS  throw a `NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID`**, you can refresh infinitly, it will allways throw it *(it can be any one, it just has to be the first one refreshed after the cert has been generated)*.
- -> **ALL the other tabs after refresh will work without a problem (even if it is the same URL as the first one that throws the error, the second tab will work)**.

**SOLUTION**: (I close and open back google chrome, all SANs URL when called will work perfectly, even the first tab).

**MY PROBLEM**: I can't close google chrome (this is necessary) and I also can't run google after the cert as been generated because google is already open and I need to rewrite the cert at any time.

that's why I need help to understand and establish why this behavior happens and if I can control it and perhaps patch it? ( I really hope it is not a google chrome behavior).